# Correct behavior in case you answered correctly

Tags: discussion

What is the correct behavior in case you provided the correct answer to a question and the OP acknowledged that your answer is the correct one but he/she didn't accept it or even upvote it?
Can I directly ask to get the upvote and/or the accept? Or this way I'll be violating the code of conduct?